# Getting Minimum Value

Tags: c#, sql

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    SELECT 
        dbo.tblDepartment.Prefix,
        dbo.tblQueue.QueueNumber, 
        dbo.tblEmployees.EmpName 
    FROM dbo.tblDepartment 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblEmployees ON dbo.tblDepartment.EmpID= dbo.tblEmployees.EmpID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQueue ON dbo.tblDepartment.DeptID = dbo.tblQueue.DeptID 
    WHERE tblDepartment.DeptID = 1 
    and tblQueue.QueueNumber in (SELECT 
                                     MIN(QueueNumber) 
                                 FROM tblQueue 
                                 WHERE tblQueue.QueueStatus = 'Pending')", con);
```

HI I have a query that's getting the minimum value where it's column status is equal to "Pending". but every time I change it's status to "Done" it gets the minimum value with the status "Done" instead of pending.

Comment: What is the problem with this query?

Comment: I have a column QueueNumber and a column QueueStatus, so I want to get the minimum Value in the column QueueNumber with a status "Pending" from column QueueStatus, but everytime I change the status from column QueueStatus to "DONE" ... it doesnt get the next minimum value with a status "Pending" so the problem is, it gets the minimum value with a status "Done" instead of a status "Pending".

Comment: @Ekko : If you  are passing "Done" in where clause, it'll return data related with Done status only

Comment: Is this returning same value every time or different ? Please verify the status really changed to `Done` or not. Is the `QueueNumber` is unique ?

Comment: still returning the same value.... the minimum value is 1 with a status pending, so when I change the status to 'DONE' it's not getting the next minimum value which is number 2 with a status 'Pending', it's still getting the previous number which is no. 1 with a status changed to DONE... and I made sure that the status is changing.

Comment: I try to reproduce the problem, and I keep asking myself what is an EmpID column doing in the tblDepartment table...

Comment: Plz show us the code, which changes status to Done in DB. Also, run the query in DB, to make sure DB reflects the changes you are looking for. By the way, it will be nice if you make it as stored procedure as the query is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your problem is not in the code, it is likely a mixup of databases or something like that.

**EDIT**: However the code does have a problem: you need to specify the DeptID inside the inner query as well, like this ([here is a demo](http://rextester.com/REKEH60781)):

```
SELECT 
    dbo.tblDepartment.Prefix,
    dbo.tblQueue.QueueNumber
    FROM dbo.tblDepartment  
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQueue ON dbo.tblDepartment.DeptID = dbo.tblQueue.DeptID 
    WHERE tblDepartment.DeptID = 2 
    and tblQueue.QueueNumber in 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QueueNumber) 
        FROM tblQueue 
        WHERE tblQueue.DeptID = 2 
            and tblQueue.QueueStatus = 'Pending'
    )
```

Comment: when you said that it's just a mixed up... I just altered the values inside the table, so it worked... but my next problem is... when I change the DeptID in the WHERE claus into 2, it's not retrieving any values

Comment: I am sorry, I missed this part completely, you didn't specify the DeptID inside the inner query as well. I updated my answer accordingly.